# Entityframework 6 : How to load only Parent type in TPT

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework-6

Example: Below is my object relationship

```
class ParentClass     {    }
class DerivedChildClass1 : ParentClass
{ 

}
class DerivedChildClass2  : ParentClass
{

}
```

My question is i am using entity framework 6 and is there is a way to load only Parent class.

Something like

```
var parentclass = DbContext.ParentClass.ToList(); 
// or something like 
var parentclass = DbContext.ParentClass.OfType<ParentClass>.ToList();
```

but it will load all the related concrete class and i have 3000 rows in database and there are 5 levels of inheritance. 
it would be very helpful if i can load only base class and then later fetch the real concrete object.